# Mean value theorem for real functions of several variables

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion

If $f\in C^2$ is a real function of two variables, we know that 
$f(x+h,y+k)-f(x,y)= hf_1(x+\theta h,y+\theta k)+kf_2(x+\theta h, y+\theta k)$ for some $\theta \in (0,1)$. I know how to derive this identity (using taylor series). However, in order to save time is there an exact analog for functions of more than two varibles?

For example, is it true that if $f\in C^2$ is a real function of three variables then $f(x+h,y+k,z+l)-f(x,y,z)= hf_1(x+\theta h,y+\theta k,z+\theta l)+kf_2(x+\theta h, y+\theta k, z+\theta l)+lf_3(x+\theta h,y+\theta k, z+\theta l)$  for a $\theta\in (0,1)$? As is clear I haven’t yet proved a similar taylor series anolog for real functions of more than two variables that’s why I wonder if my guess is correct.

Comment: What are the $f_{k}$ and how are they related to $f$?  Are they partial derivatives?

Comment: $f_1$ is the partial derivative with respect to the first argument and so on @avs

Comment: Ok.  You fill find the formula you are seeking  in Section 8.4.1 of [Mathematical Analysis, Vol I, by Zorich](https://books.google.com/books?id=qA5FTMT7HE4C&source=gbs_navlinks_s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define $$g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, g(t)=f(x_1+th_1, x_2+th_2, \dots, x_n +th_n)$$
Then everything reduces to the mean value theorem of one variable. Because you get
$$ g(1)-g(0)= g'(\Theta)$$
for some $\Theta\in (0;1)$ by the mean value theorem. However, by the Leibniz formula and the chain rule you obtain for the derivate
$$ g'(t)= \sum_{j=1}^n f_j(x_1 + t h_1, \dots, x_n + th_n)\cdot (t h_j)' = \sum_{j=1}^n h_n \cdot f_j(x_1 + th_1, \dots, x_n + t h_n) $$
which is exactly your expression.

Comment: I know how to prove a higher dimensional analog but I only want to know if my guess is correct

Comment: You wrote that you don't know how to prove it... also if you did, you wouldn't need to guess (because then you knew that it is correct).

Comment: I didn’t write that I didn’t know how to prove it. Anyway thanks for your complete answer

Comment: You wrote: "As is clear I haven’t yet proved a similar taylor series anolog for real functions of more than two variables that’s why I wonder if my guess is correct." I wonder how I should interpret this then :)

Comment: Linguistically it means “I am too bored to try proving such analogs brushing up on calculus” :D

Comment: I see ^^ it always seemed useful to me to do this boring things to get a real understanding (and it's nice to see that one can prove something)

Comment: Almost all my questions here are questions that I was too bored to try my best to solve. But I solve problems of my interest myself

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your guess is correct.  You fill find the formula you are anticipating in Section 8.4.1 of [Mathematical Analysis, Vol I, by Zorich](https://books.google.com/books?id=qA5FTMT7HE4C&source=gbs_navlinks_s).

Comment: Thanks I’ll check the book